# swap rows matrix C++

Tags: c++, matrix, rows

hello I have a problem with my program, i wanna swap rows in matrix with the next structure:

first and last row.

second and second to last row.

until N to N values.

Note: I used `#define n 4` but i need to be able to do it for any value of n.

Input:

```
3 4 5 0
2 6 1 2
2 7 1 2
2 1 1 2
```

Output:

```
2 1 1 2
2 7 1 2
2 6 1 2
3 4 5 0
```

This program only changes the first and the last row:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define n 4 

void interchange(int m[][n])
{
    int rows = n;


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int t = m[0][i];
        m[0][i] = m[rows - 1][i];
        m[rows - 1][i] = t;
    }
}


int main()
{

    int m[n][n] = {
        { 8, 9, 7, 6 },
        { 4, 7, 6, 5 },
        { 3, 2, 1, 8 },
        { 9, 9, 7, 7 }
    };

    interchange(m);


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: You can simply print/use your matrix rows starting from `n` instead of `0` no need of any swapping at all.

Comment: Make the interchange function take two more arguments - the rows that it is supposed to swap. Then this program will become quite similar to reversing a 1-D array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a loop by rows from `0` to `n/2` (`for (int i = 0; i < n/2; ++i)`). And one more loop by elements in each row (`for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)`)

You have to swap each element from row with index `i` with each element in row with index `n-i-1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#define n 4

void interchange(int m[][n]) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; ++i) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            std::swap(m[i][j], m[n-i-1][j]);
        }
    }
} 

int main()
{
    int m[n][n] = { { 8, 9, 7, 6 }, 
            { 4, 7, 6, 5 }, 
            { 3, 2, 1, 8 }, 
            { 9, 9, 7, 7 } }; 


    interchange(m);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            std::cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use additional loop  to go through rows from first to last row, like this:

```
void interchange(int m[][n]) 
{ 
    int lastRow = n - 1; 

    for (int j = 0; j <= lastRow / 2; j++ ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            int t = m[j][i]; 
            m[j][i] = m[lastRow - j][i]; 
            m[lastRow - j][i] = t; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `m[rows - j]` at first iteration it will be `m[4-0]` hence out of bound. Hence UB.

Comment: @kiranBiradar, fixed

Comment: `lastRow / 2` wrong again, it will be `3/2` hence you loop one less row.

Comment: @kiranBiradar, changed condition to `j <= lastRow / 2`. Seems to work